# How can I grep contents of files with bash only without using find or grep -r?

Tags: bash, unix

I have an assignment to write a bash program which if I type in the following:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./sample.sh path regex keyword
```

that will result something like that:

```
path/sample.txt:12
path/sample.txt:34
path/dir/sample1.txt:56
path/dir/sample2.txt:78
```

The numbers are the line number of the search results. I have absolutely no idea how can I achieve this in bash, without using `find` or `grep -r`. I am allowed to use `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, …

Comment: why can't you use `grep` or `find`?

Comment: i am trying to do a coursework which forbids us to use those... i have absolutely no idea what else i can do...

Comment: Please help... I'm very desperate...

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem into parts.

- First, you need to obtain the file names to search in. How can you list the files in a directory and its subdirectories? (Hint: there's a glob pattern for that.)
- You need to iterate over the files. What form of loop should this be?
- For each file, you need to read each line from the file in turn. There's a builtin for that.
- For each line, you need to test whether the line matches the specified regexp. There's a construct for that.
- You need to maintain a counter of the number of lines read in a file to be able to print the line number.

> Search for `globstar` in the bash manual.
>  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936 regarding `while read` loops.

---

```
shopt -s globstar       # to enable **/
GLOBIGNORE=.:..         # to match dot files
dir=$1; regex=$2
for file in "$dir"/**/*; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue
  n=1
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
      echo "$file:$n"
    fi
    ((++n))
  done <"$file"
done
```

---

It's possible that your teacher didn't intend you to use the `globstar` feature, which is a relatively recent addition to bash (appeared in version 4.0). If so, you'll need to write a recursive function to recurse into subdirectories.

```
traverse_directory () {
  for x in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -d "$x" ]; then
      traverse_directory "$x"
    elif [ -f "$x" ]; then
      grep "$regexp" "$x"
    fi
  done
}
```

Putting this into practice:

```
#!/bin/sh
regexp="$2"
traverse_directory "$1"
```

Follow-up exercise: the glob pattern `*` omits files whose name begins with a `.` (dot files). You can easily match dot files as well by adding looping over `.*` as well, i.e. `for x in .* *; do …`. However, this throws the function into an infinite loop as it recurses forever into `.` (and also `..`). How can you change the function to work with dot files as well?

Comment: Wow, this is quite something. I immediately cancelled writing my solution the moment I read yours. Thank you!

Comment: i'm very sorry but i am extremely new to these so i don't understand those really... my bash is 3.2 so i dont have globstar on it... if I am using the second option, what should I do with the traverse_directory function? Many thanks!

Comment: @user1959859 Call the function on the top directory, e.g. `traverse_directory path`.

Comment: If this is difficult, start by writing a script that only handles the file in the specified directory, without doing the recursive traversal. Once you understand that first part, add the recursive traversal.

Comment: i wrote something like that before:

#!/bin/bash


    ls ./"$1" > temp.txt

    grep "$2" ./temp.txt

Comment: but erm... of course it didn't work... and I spend like 15 hours... writing 2 lines... :'(

Comment: Note: this will break if your file does not end with a newline, or contains embedded nulls.

Comment: very nice. To be pedantic, though, the `for x in "$1"/*; do` part only goes into subdirs and subfiles that doesn't start by an "." ... ^^  You could replace with : `for x in "$1"/* "$1"/.* ; do ` (+ add as the first command after the "do" a test that will `continue` if "$x" is "." or "..")

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while read
do
  [[ $REPLY =~ foo ]] && echo $REPLY
done < file.txt
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! erm... actually i can use grep but i can't use recursive grep... but then the code has to find files recursively, how can I do that? thanks again!!

Comment: Make that loop [`while IFS= read -r`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936).